# Is it possible to render specific projection, without a camera?

Tags: rendering, orthographic

I would like to render elements for 2D game and was thinking it is possible to render, say, just TOP ORTHO.

But unfortunately, I can't find an option.

If I set additional camera with orthographic mode, then how to set exact range to render? `Orthographic scale` parameter is not intuitive.

**UPDATE**

If found a button for this:

[image]

Is there any way to call this from menu and control some options?

Comment: Orthographic scale seems to set the BU (blender units) for the camera range width, or height, depending on the longest side in the render output. Eg. if 1920x1080, so setting Orthographic scale = 1 means that 1920 will be 1 BU.

Comment: It is somehow possible with Baking (http://imgur.com/CZkdbIW), but I wouldn't suggest it as a solution. Could you explain in which sense the Ortographic camera isnìt good for this job?

Comment: You might get some hints here: https://youtu.be/09-cUN2pYBw